# Erro <generator object <genexpr> ao ler matriz em Python

Tags: python

Quero ler matriz colocando as vírgulas para separar os números, mas quando peço para mostrar a matriz, ele dá esse erro:

> `<generator object <genexpr>`

Isso nunca me aconteceu, não faço a mínima ideia de como regularizar.
Segue abaixo o código:

```
leia =input('Digite a dimensão da matriz: ')
vet = [float (x) for x in leia.split(',')]
matriz = []

for i in range (len(vet)):
    linha =[]
    linha.append(float(x) for x in input(f'Digite a linha {i}: ').split(','))
    matriz.append(linha)
    
print('Matriz digitada:')
for linha in matriz:
    print(linha)
```

Comment: leia =input('Digite a dimensão da matriz: ')
vet = [float (x) for x in leia.split(',')]
matriz = []


for i in range (len(vet)):
    linha =[]
    linha.append(float(x) for x in input(f'Digite a linha {i}: ').split(','))
    matriz.append(linha)

print('Matriz digitada:')
for linha in matriz:
    print(linha)

Comment: Troque a linha `linha.append(float(x) for x in input(f'Digite a linha {i}: ').split(','))` por `linha.extend(float(x) for x in input(f'Digite a linha {i}: ').split(','))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você precisa usar um objeto `tuple()` ou `list()` para converter o resultado da expressão que está gerando sua matriz, mais precisamente no seu `for`.

código funcionando:

```
leia = input('Digite a dimensão da matriz: ')
vet = [float(x) for x in leia.split(',')]
matriz = []

for i in range(len(vet)):
    linha = []
    linha.append(tuple(float(x) for x in input(f'Digite a linha {i}: ').split(',')))
    matriz.append(linha)

print('Matriz digitada:')
for linha in matriz:
    print(linha)
```

Comment: Muito obrigaaaa, deu certo :D